# sIFR: Not working for custom divs more than once

Tags: replace, sifr, html

Using sIFR rev. 436, latest release.  Replaces h1, h2, h3, h4 tags flawlessy, as many as I have on the page.  However, if i try replacing a custom div, say Replace Me it replaces only the first instance, but not the others on the page.  I tested this on the 2.0 release as well and got the same results.  Is this just a limitation of the software that it won't let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

Is "Replace Me" a class or an id?

Paste relevant pieces of code that shows what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Check out the link here, I've got three divs with the id of champion, only one gets replaced.  I also have three h1 tags, all three get replaced.

LINK:

http://work.mrmworldwideprn.com/Client/Applebees/sIFR/applebees/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute has to have a unique value, having more than one element with the same id is wrong.

To use the same styling for multiple elements use the class attribute.

replace this html

```
<div id="champion">DELICIOUS APPETIZERS</div>
<div id="champion">Appetizers</div>
<div id="champion">Ulitimate Trios</div>
```

with

```
<div class="champion">DELICIOUS APPETIZERS</div>
<div class="champion">Appetizers</div>
<div class="champion">Ulitimate Trios</div>
```

And replace this in your sifr config

```
sIFR.replace(champion, {
  selector: '#champion',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #c21212; }'
});
```

with this

```
sIFR.replace(champion, {
  selector: '.champion',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #c21212; }'
});
```

Comment: That worked great thanks!  Now on IE7 my H6 tags get replaced with flash and then disappear from the screen.

Check this link:

http://72.32.182.2/v4/menulanding.aspx

Any ideas why this is happening?  Check it in FF to see what it should look like.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Belay my last...there was a 5px bottom margin on the image that was pushing the text down, making it disappear.  Thanks again for all of your help!